# Generate IF conditions from function

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an if statement that is used in two different functions against the same conditions. The problem is that the conditions end up fairly long (5-7 ORs) and may need to be modified in the future. If they end up being modified, the conditions will change the same way in both functions.

Example of one if statement:

```
if ($this->object === 'one' || $this->object === 'two' || $this->object === 'three' ) {
    echo 'Yes!';
} else {
    echo 'No!';
};
```

I am thinking of creating an array and a function that will feed into the if statement but can't think of any way to get the if statement to check the condition rather than checking the presence of input.

```
$this->object = 'one';
$test_array = array('one', 'two', 'three');

function stmbuilder($array) {
    $count = count($array);
    $stm = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $intro = '$this->object ===';
        $connector = ($i < $count-1 ? ' || ' : '');
        $stm .= $intro . $array[$i] . $connector;
    }

    return $stm;
}

$condition = stmbuilder($test_array);

if ($condition) {
    echo 'Yes!';
} else {
    echo 'No!';
} //Will always echo Yes! since $condition has a value but does not check against what $this->object is
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `if(in_array($this->object, $test_array, true))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just `in_array()`?

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');

in_array('four', $arr) -> false
in_array('two', $arr) -> true
```